# Values for not getting updated in entry boxes after selecting(curseselection)

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

i am not able to figure what is causing this error. What i am trying to achieve is 6 entry boxes getting updated based on the data selected in listbox

```
def showSelected(event):
    sel = lis.curselection()[0]
    itm = lis.get(sel)
       
    var.set(itm)
    print(itm)
    print(type(itm))

    date_entry.delete(0,END)
    date_entry.insert(END,itm[1])
    earn_entry.delete(0,END)
    earn_entry.insert(END,itm[2])
    excerise_entry.delete(0,END)
    excerise_entry.insert(END,itm[3])
    study_entry.delete(0,END)
    study_entry.insert(END,itm[4])
    diet_entry.delete(0,END)
    diet_entry.insert(END,itm[5])
    python_entry.delete(0,END)
    python_entry.insert(END,itm[6])


lis.bind('<<ListboxSelection>>', showSelected)
```

Comment: What is wrong here. Also, the event is called 'ListboxSelect', so: `lis.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', showSelected)`

Comment: Oh my god, such a silly mistake :-P... thank you so much